# sql query with a count

Tags: mysql, sql

im sure this is easy but im having a block I am trying to write some sql against a single table that has (simplified for example)

```
RunName, Result
foo,     pass
foo,     pass
foo,     fail 
foo,     pass
boo,     pass
boo,     fail
boo,     fail
soo,     pass
```

I was a query that will return a count of pass or fail for each name

something like for fail

```
foo, 1
boo, 2
soo, 0
```

and for pass

```
foo, 3
boo, 1
soo, 1
```

Comment: you need to revise your question, it is not clear what you want to know

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't tag a question with two different flavors of RDBMS.

Comment: sorry it was mysql but we also use sql server for similar result storage so I added it as both.  MySql working is fine for what I needed

Comment: Then it is still not a SQL Server question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you'd do a simple COUNT and GROUP BY RunName, but [*that will not show "zero results" like soo's fails*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffcfe/4).

This should work even for zero results (on MySQL)

```
SELECT RunName, SUM(Result='fail')
FROM TableA
GROUP BY RunName;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffcfe/7).

Edit: As Aaron points out, that only works on MySQL, this works on SQL Server also;

```
SELECT  RunName, SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as fails
FROM   TableA
GROUP BY RunName
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffcfe/4).

Edit2: As Marcus points out, it's may not be a very index friendly way of doing the query, so if you have a primary key you may be better off doing a self join with a count/group to get the correct result;

```
SELECT a.RunName, COUNT(b.Result)
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableA b ON a.id=b.id AND b.Result='fail'
GROUP BY RunName
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a427e/2).

Comment: This will work in MySQL, but boolean expressions are not supported that way in SQL Server. I realize the question is tagged as both, so it is unclear.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ah, only saw the MySQL part, I'll revise for both.

Comment: you know its a stupid question when you get 6 answers in minutes :)  this worked as did some others thanks

Comment: Tag for SQL Server is `SQL Server`. `SQL` is for generic SQL.

Comment: @MarcusAdams The tag was changed, see discussion below the question.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Any suggestions how to get the correct result using COUNT and no primary key to self join on? soo's fails won't show up with a regular count/group, and the question specifically displays them.

Comment: @MarcusAdams See the link in italics right at the top. No count for soo's fails while the question mentions them in the expected result.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Ah, I'm so sorry. I missed that entirely in the question. +1

Answer (score 2):

This is for all the fail results, just change the `where` clause for pass:

```
select RunName, count(Result)
from [tableName]
where Result = 'fail'
group by RunName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for `fail`

```
select RunName, count(Result) as cnt
from your_table
where Result = 'fail'
group by RunName
```

and this for `pass`

```
select RunName, count(Result) as cnt
from your_table
where Result = 'pass'
group by RunName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a group by.

Something like this

```
Select count(result), runname, result from sometable
group by runname, result
```

this should give you output like

count runname result

2     foo     pass

3     foo     fail

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT  RunName, SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumPass,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumFail
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY RunName
```

If you want separate results for each then you can just do a filter on the where clause like so:

```
    SELECT  RunName, COUNT(1) as NumPass
    FROM    yourtable
    WHERE   Result = 'pass'
GROUP BY RunName


SELECT  RunName, COUNT(1) as NumFail
FROM    yourtable
WHERE   Result = 'fail'
GROUP BY RunName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For Pass:

```
SELECT RunName, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Result
WHERE UPPER(Result) = 'PASS'
```

For Fail:

```
SELECT RunName, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Result
WHERE UPPER(Result) = 'FAIL'
```

Comment: `UPPER()` isn't necessary here. It causes an extra filesort for the `GROUP BY`, rather than using an index on `Result`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams First of all you are ASSuming that the OP is using SQL Server,  and Second of all not all RDBS are case agnostic (ie Oracle). I develop software that runs against 10 different databases so I write my SQL queries to run against all databases.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` and `WHERE Result = 'pass'`. I wouldn't assume, given the data provided by the OP, that data will include 'PASS' and 'pass'.  I was offering criticism on using a function in `GROUP BY` and didn't even notice you don't have a WHERE clause. -2 for scanning all rows.

Comment: @MarcusAdams -  Ok, now I see what you were talking about originally, I just edited my code.

Comment: If you improve your query, or at least explain your reasoning for assuming the column will be mixed case, I will remove the down vote. Don't take it personally, dude. Even with the `WHERE` clause, you're still scanning all rows unless you remove the `UPPER()` function, but at least you tried.

Comment: @MarcusAdams will if I was about to I am not now DB!